# What type do we need to use with checkbox event onchange?

Tags: typescript

What type do we need to use with checkbox event onchange using pure javascript with typescript?

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector("#myCheckbox") as HTMLInputElement;

function handleCheckboxChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        console.log("Checkbox is checked");
    } else {
        console.log("Checkbox is not checked");
    }
}
```

checkbox.onchange = handleCheckboxChange;

The above solution gives the following error

```
type ChangeEvent = /*unresolved*/ any
Cannot find name 'ChangeEvent'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you're importing the interface from react in your document, eg:

```
import { ChangeEvent } from "react";
```

Or, use namespace React.ChangeEvent, eg:

```
function handleCheckboxChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        console.log("Checkbox is checked");
    } else {
        console.log("Checkbox is not checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).